# ANTLR4 CharStream class missing

Tags: java, maven, docker, pom.xml, antlr4

I am using ANTLR4 to parse command lines for my Java Shell project.
When I run a JUnit test in VSCode, everything is fine. However, when I am building the Docker image and I try to run the shell in interactive mode, I get this error:

> Error: Unable to initialize main class uk.ac.ucl.jsh.Jsh
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStream

Is there any issue with my pom.xml file, or is the problem coming from somewhere else? This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>uk.ac.ucl.jsh</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsh</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jsh</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>uk.ac.ucl.jsh.Jsh</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
          <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.7.2</version>         
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>antlr4</goal>
              </goals>            
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
              <visitor>true</visitor>
              <listener>true</listener>
              <outputDirectory>
                  ${basedir}/src/main/java/
              </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>    
        </plugin>          
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <reportSets>
            <reportSet>
              <reports>
                <!-- select non-aggregate reports -->
                <report>report</report>
              </reports>
            </reportSet>
          </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you try defining dependency `antlr4-runtime` for `maven-jar-plugin` plugin configuration?

Comment: @ImGroot I tried now, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really look like an ANTLR problem.  You'll need to look into how you're doing your build and how you're putting your Docker image together.

There are a couple of solutions to this.

- Look into how to have Maven produce an Uber jar (i.e. a jar file that bundles up all of it's dependencies)
- Ensure that your Docker image has the ANTLR runtime included and in your class path.

The first of those is probably the more "normal" solutions these days.